# Material UI Select focus and selected background color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have Select component and MenuItems inside it and I want to remove or override background color from focused Select component and selected MenuItem.

Selected MenuItem has this background color:

[image]

And after I select item Select component has focus which looks like this:

[image]

Here is my Select component and MenuItem inside it:

```
<Select
    classes={{ focused: classes.selected }}
>
    <MenuItem
        classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
    >
        Never
    </MenuItem>
</Select>
```

and I'm just tried to override background color to be same as normally:

```
focused: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
},

selected: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
},
```

Any tips how to remove or override those background colors? Select component doesn't have to keep it's focus after option is selected.

**EDIT:** Found out where focused appears and I'm pretty sure I need to target it via inputProps but don't know how:

[image]

Comment: change your `focused` and `selected` to `focusedA` and `selectedA` and create 
new `focused` and `selected` empty and then call them like `className={classes.focusedA} and `classes={{focused: classes.focused}}` and the same for selected

Comment: Can't get this work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to change the bg of the focused `Select` component target the `root` class using `classes` prop and add `:hover` styles.

```
<Select classes={{ root: classes.selectRoot }}>
{... menuitems}
</Select>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  selectRoot: {
  //...other styles
    '&:focus':{
      backgroundColor:'yellow'
    }
  }
}));
```

And for changing the bg of the selected `MenuItem`,  something similar needs to be done. For this target the `selected` and `root` class of the `MenuItem`.

```
<MenuItem
  classes={{ selected: classes.selected, root: classes.rootMenuItem }}
  value={"1"}>
  Never
</MenuItem>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  selected: {
  },
  rootMenuItem: {
    "&$selected": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "green"
         }
      },
    '&:hover':{
      backgroundColor:'blue'
    }
  }
}));
```

*Another way of styling `MenuItem`*:-
Giving the classes `classes={{ selected: classes.selected, root: classes.rootMenuItem }}` to every `ListItem` is not preferable it'll increase the code repetition and also violets some clean code rules (if followed). So to overcome this create a custom listItem using `withStyles`.

```
const CustomMenuItem = withStyles((theme) =>createStyles({
  root:{
        "&$selected": {
            backgroundColor: "red",
            "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: "green"
            }
    },
    '&:hover':{
      backgroundColor:'blue'
    }
  },
  selected:{
    
  }
})
)(MenuItem);
```

Now use this `CustomMenuItem`  in place of `ListItem`.

```
<Select classes={{ root: classes.selectRoot }}>
  <CustomMenuItem value={"1"}>Never1</CustomMenuItem>
  <CustomMenuItem value={"2"}>Never2</CustomMenuItem>
  <CustomMenuItem value={"3"}>Never3</CustomMenuItem>
</Select>
```

*Note:- I've added random background colors here.*

Working demo:-
[image: Edit hidden-leaf-63jme]

Answer (score 1):

After read your suggestion, I added `:focus` to the global theme in my `App.js` file, like that:

```
MuiSelect: {
  outlined: {
    '&:focus': {
      backgroundColor: '#FFF'
    }
  }
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easist way is:

style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}

```
            <Select
                labelId='demo-simple-select-filled-label'
                id='demo-simple-select-filled'
                displayEmpty
                value={age}
                onChange={handleChange}
                style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
            >
```